# Can there be a redirect to a foreign domain while suing enforced https?

Tags: redirect, https, github-pages, cloudflare

I am using guthub pages to host a simple website with a custom domain. To manage the the DNS I am using CloudFlare.

I had pages rules setup on CloudFlare for forwarding to my google drive file:

```
example.com/pdf Foreward rule code 301 https://drive.google.com/file/d/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

A while back I enabled HTTPS for my custom domain. Domain is assigned to the guthub page using CNAME and on the github settings page I have enabled `Forced HTTPS`

I only recently noticed my short links to the google drive files were down.

Is this due to HTTPS? Can replicate forwarding to foreign domain effect without compromising on HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that site-wide SSL is reflected in the rule, because Cloudflare first enforces the SSL and only then processes the rules.

http**s**://example.com/pdf 301 https://drive.google.com/file/.........

Comment: I am still getting githubs 404 page.
Unless there is a significant time delay until it takes effect.

Comment: It isn't clear from your post but I assume you are using a subdomain, since using CNAME on a bare domain is not RFC-compliant. Still, I am surprised because a very similar setup works for me. As a less-than-perfect solution, you can try to have the doc on a subdomain, for example pdf.domain.com (set any CNAME or A record and then add a redirect rule).